# SelectOneMenu do Primefaces seleciona um item ao pressionar uma tecla de atalho com CTRL

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Tenho formulários em JSF com alguns atalhos de teclado, por exemplo, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> aciona o submit para salvar os dados.

O problema é que, quando uma combinação de teclas é pressionada em um campo `<p:selectOneMenu>`, o primeiro item começando com `S` (conforme o exemplo) é selecionado e depois o formulário é submetido.

É possível reproduzir este comportamento acessando o [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf), selecionando o primeiro campo e pressionando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. No Chrome, pelo menos, ele irá selecionar a primeira opção e então abrir o diálogo "Abrir arquivo" (*Open*).

Minha intenção é que o componente ignore a letra digitada se uma tecla especial estiver pressionada.

Testei o componente html `SELECT` e o combo do jQuery UI e não ocorre o mesmo comportamento. Pelo jeito, o PrimeFaces usa um *wrapper* diferente para um campo `input`.

Tentei adicionar um  `return false` tanto no evento do atributo `onkeydown` quanto no `onkeyup` conforme o User Guide. Nada feito.

Tentei ainda adicionar eventos de teclado pelo jQuery com `preventDefault()` e `return false`. Nada.

Bem, antes de baixar o fonte do PrimeFaces e começar a fuçar, alguém tem alguma ideia de como contornar essa situação?

---

#### Atualização

Mais detalhes sobre o componente.

Abrindo a [página do showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf), cliquei no primeiro componente e deixei o `SELECT` aberto.

Pressionei <kbd>F12</kbd> para abrir o console e digitei `document.activeElement`. O resultado foi um `input`:

```html
<input id="j_idt18:j_idt22_focus" name="j_idt18:j_idt22_focus" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Entendo que este é o campo que realmente fica com o valor e recebe os eventos. Ele deve ter um event handler que seleciona o item quando se pressiona uma letra, mas com certeza faltou um tratamento para o caso das teclas especiais como <kbd>CTRL</kbd> e <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Comment: Em que elemento você tentou anular o evento? Não sei nada do primefaces, mas pelo exemplo linkado parece que teria de ser no `.ui-selectonemenu-panel` ou em algo dentro dele. Foi isso?

Comment: No meu windows o CTR dispara "salvar a página", e o `S` escolhe a primeira `option`do select que começa com `S`. Não sei se compreendí bem o problema.

Comment: @bfavaretto Os eventos `onkeydown` e `onkeyup` são do componente do PF e não cheguei a olhar onde eles foram injetados no código gerado. Já os códigos do jQuery eu injetei num campo `input` que fica oculto. Em meus testes, verifiquei que esse campo oculto fica com o foco enquanto o campo está selecionado.

Comment: @Sergio Se tiver um item que começa com a letra "S" e você pressionar `CTRL+S` para salvar, além de abrir o diálogo, o item que começa com a letra "S" vai ser selecionado. O usuário vai salvar o cadastro com o item errado sem perceber.

Comment: Provavelmente os listeners do próprio primefaces são executados antes dos seus, e aí é tarde demais pra cancelar.

Comment: aha... já percebí o problema. o que você que é tipo `if(CTR pressionado) ignorar a outra tecla` certo?

Comment: @Sergio Exatamente!

Comment: @bfavaretto Provavelmente é isso. Não consegui pensar num jeito de contornar isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contornei o problema recuperando uma versão posterior da biblioteca PrimeFaces a partir do repositório SVN. Algumas funções Javascript estava corrigidas.

Extraí as funções corrigidas e adicionei um arquivo Javascript para sobrescrever as incorretas da versão com problemas.

O código é:

```js
/**
 * Fix for selectOneMenu when key is pressed along with CTRL
 */
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu = PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.extend({

    bindKeyEvents: function() {
        var $this = this;

        this.focusInput.on('keydown.ui-selectonemenu', function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;

            switch(key) {
                case keyCode.UP:
                case keyCode.LEFT:
                    $this.highlightPrev(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.DOWN:
                case keyCode.RIGHT:
                    $this.highlightNext(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    $this.handleEnterKey(e);
                break;

                case keyCode.TAB:
                    $this.handleTabKey();
                break;

                case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                    $this.handleEscapeKey(e);
                break;
            }
        })
        .on('keyup.ui-selectonemenu', function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;
            switch(key) {
                case keyCode.UP:
                case keyCode.LEFT:
                case keyCode.DOWN:
                case keyCode.RIGHT:
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                case keyCode.TAB:
                case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                break;

                default:
                    var text = $(this).val(),
                    matchedOptions = null;

                    clearTimeout($this.searchTimer);

                    matchedOptions = $this.options.filter(function() {
                        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) === 0;
                    });

                    if(matchedOptions.length) {
                        var highlightItem = $this.items.eq(matchedOptions.index());
                        if($this.panel.is(':hidden')) {
                            $this.selectItem(highlightItem);
                        }
                        else {
                            $this.highlightItem(highlightItem);
                            PrimeFaces.scrollInView($this.itemsWrapper, highlightItem);
                        }
                    }

                    $this.searchTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                        $this.focusInput.val('');
                    }, 1000);

                break;
            }
        });
    }
});
```